# Dynamic Match Formula based on Date Criteria (G-sheets)

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking to return a match on an array of data, depending on what the current date is.

Sheet located here for reference: (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jHw8y8AObnvJEW3YiSb_kGXZFfxHW96UjfFh_6NVaXQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Essentially I have 10 workers that can possibly appear on the roster, which will vary day to day. I'd like to link this to a google script which will automatically trigger an email to the workers that will be in the office the next day.

My issue is that I'm not sure how to create a dynamic reference so that my index-match formula knows which column to refer to. I'd like the formula to detect what tomorrow's date is, and as such return a 1 or 0 for who is rostered for the day. I've tried several Index-match-match methods but with no avail, as I have a broad range of potential columns to return data from.

Hope this makes sense, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hello there @Dingo, the sheet you have posted *cannot* be accessed. Can you provide the formula you have used and *what* exactly is the end-goal in this situation? Moreover, can you please specify what you have *tried* to accomplish the task?

Comment: sheet is private